# Is it possible to finish Fragment class in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Normally if we would like to close the activity means what we will do, we will simply call

```
finish()
```

method right.Likewise,how can we finish or close **a FRAGMENT class**.

Suggestion please..

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: There is no finish for fragment. Its attached to the activity.

Comment: popBackstack could do it

Comment: You cant not finish fragment but you can do it with by maintaing BackStacks.

Comment: I think if you want to `dismiss/finish` your current `fragment` the best way to do this is as simple as by doing `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> getActivity().finish()

Use this method

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove%28android.app.Fragment%29

You normally start a fragment via FragmentManager and FragmentTransactions - you can probably use the remove command from FragmentTransactions